# If $f$ is continuous and bounded on $\Bbb{R}$, does it mean that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\Bbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Please, I need some clarification on this. If $f$ is continuous and bounded on $\Bbb{R}$, does it mean that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\Bbb{R}$?

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @ T. Bongers: Why?

Comment: @ T. Bongers: Any counterexample?

Comment: Because there are tons of counterexamples; can you share what research you've done about this question, and what you've tried to answer it? For example: googling the phrase "continuous bounded function uniformly continuous" gave an answer from this very site.

Comment: Have you tried playing around at all @Mike

Comment: @ qbert: Yes, I'm playing around right now! The question requires me to prove or provide a counterexample.

Comment: What about $h(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x},\;x\neq 1.$ The function $\bar{h}$ defined on $\Bbb{R}$ by   $\bar{h}(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{\sin x}{x}, &  x \neq 0\\1 & x=0\end{cases}$

Comment: Your post has been closed so I answer this way hoping you can read it. Take the function $f(x)= \sin(e^x)$ as a good counterexample.

Comment: @Piquito: Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome. (The example is very good really, I like it. In my answer I told you is important keep in mind that EACH OPEN BOULE of radius $\delta$ is contained in an open ball of radius $\epsilon$. With this idea you can try to get another good example).